# Make multiple docker instances from one docker-compose file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, cypress

I have a single Rails API which runs in docker, along with other dependent containers (database, sidekiq, etc).

I'd like to essentially duplicate the stack to run a separate instance locally to run cypressJS tests against, to maintain two different sets of data in my DB.

Is there an easy way to do this?  I've read that the `-p` option can let you do this but I can't find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was the following:-

```
docker-compose --project-name rails-api-cypress up -d rails-api
```

Where `rails-api-cypress` is my new duplicate test container, and rails-api is the container it's duplicating.

I was getting errors with the --project-name flag before because the container needs to be stopped first.

Conveniently, this also clones dependent containers so you have a completely separate stack.